# description of the field in mongoengine

Tags: comments, documentation, mongoengine

is there any way to add a description / hint to the field in the mongoengine model?

I have a situation when inline comments are entered before the line with the definition of the field, because it is not possible to explain the full meaning of this field only with name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's really better but you can take advantage of the `**kwargs` of the Field constructor like this

```
class FunkyDoc(Document):
    s = StringField(required=True, custom_doc="Lorem ipsum blablablablabla")
```

Unknown parameters aren't taken into account so this won't interfer with MongoEngine internals